# Signed and unsigned integers with logical operators

Tags: c, casting, operators

```
int x = /* some integer */; 
unsigned int ux = (unsigned) x;
```

we have

```
x >= 0 || x < ux
```

we know that in `x < ux` the first `x` is cast implicitly to `unsigned` but is the first `x` in `x >= 0` (1) cast to `unsigned` implicitly?

Comment: Detail: `x` is not _cast_ - there is no cast in `x < ux`.  `x` is _converted_ to an `unsigned`.

Answer (score 4):

No. It happens operator by operator.

```
x >= 0 || x < ux
```

is naturally

```
(x >= 0) || (x < ux)
```

Since `x` and `0` are both `int`s, there is no need for any [(usual arithmetic) conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8)...

And even though `x` is converted to *unsigned* in `x < ux`, the *value* of the expression `x < ux` is of type `int` - either `0` or `1` (just like on the the left-hand side).

Answer (score 1):

No it isn’t.

This is because x >= 0 is an expression. (Formally 0 is an octal constant of type int.)

Try 1 / 2 * 1.0 for a more pernicious example. This is grouped as (1 / 2) * 1.0 and is zero since the integers in the expression 1 / 2 are not promoted to floating point.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense

Answer (score 0):

No, `0` is an `int`, so there are no promotions in the `x >= 0` part of your expression.